# so i was trying to make a ban command using discord.js V12 and i am always getting the same error no matter what

Tags: node.js, discord.js

a ban command sound simple and  i know i could just copy one on the internet but i wanted to make a more specific ban command with arguments like time and looks like this :

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.client;
//message is an array of strings from  the message the user send
//and args is everything after the !ban so the mention is args[0]

module.exports = {
    name : 'ban',
    description : 'bans any user for as long as you want(unit in days)',
    execute(message, args) {
        if(!message.mentions.users.first()) {
            return message.channel.send('please specify a target');
        }
        // target is who will be banned
        const target = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
        // time is how long will the user be banned (in days) it's mutiplied by 1 to convert it from a stirng to  NaN or a number parseInt() works too :)
        const time = args[1] * 1;
        // checks if there are any arguments
        if(args.length === 1) {
            message.channel.send('you have not input a reason and a time for the ban');
            return;
        }
        else if(!isNaN(time)) {
            // this is where the problem is
            try {
                target.send('you were banned, dummy accout'); // << this works
                target.ban({ reason:args.slice(2).join(' '), days:time }); // << but this doesn't
                /* (node:10484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
delete_message_days: int value should be less than or equal to 7. */
            }
            catch(error) {
                // this code does not execute
                console.error(error);
                message.reply('there was an issue executing the command');
            }
            return;
        }
// this one works as well only when i dont give a time for the ban (if the if statement above returns false )
        else if(typeof args[1] === 'string') {
            target.ban({ reason:args.slice(1).join(' ') });
            return;
        }
    },

};
```

i already set up a command handler and every command  i have  works fine but on this one i keep getting this error
(node:10484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
delete_message_days: int value should be less than or equal to 7.
and funny enough, if i typed !ban @user  and then anything less than 7 it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) its pretty clear that the `days` needs to be a value between 0 and 7.
If you want to delete older messages you would need to do it by manually fetching them and then using `Message#delete()` or `TextChannel#bulkDelete()`.